# Form validation: text has to be a number

Tags: forms

I have a textfield in a form that must contain a number. Using an integer for the field type is not possible - it must be text; however, I need to ensure that the input is actually a number. I've used:

```
function myfunc_form_user_register_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (!is_numeric($form_state['values']['number'])) {
    form_set_error('number', t('Field must be Numeric'));
  }
}
```

However, it does not work, that is, no errors are ever displayed. I have implemented the above code in `template.php`. I know there are Form Validation modules; however, I would like to do such a simple thing myself. I also think it's a bit overkill to create a whole module to simply validate a single field in a single form! I also wonder how to find the `$form[]` keys. I named the input field `number` so I imagine that's the key but it's just a guess. I've looked through the Form API and it is not very clear what I am supposed to do. Simple things, such as finding out what's even in `$form[]` alludes me and it doesn't seem to be clearly explained.

Comment: How have you attached the validate handler to the form? Are you 100% sure `myfunc_form_user_register_form_validate` has been invoked?

Comment: 1) I assume so: `$form['#validate'][] = "myfunc_form_user_register_form_validate";`                                                  2) Yes, it is being called.

Comment: I would check `$form_state['values']['number']` in that case - as far as PHP is concerned, the string doesn't contain a valid number (that's the only way `is_numeric` would fail)

Comment: Sorry Clive, I made an error: the method is not being called! The `form_alter` method is running (`$form['#validate'][] = "myfunc_form_user_register_form_validate";`

Comment: No worries, that's actually a more straightforward method to accomplish this anyway, I've chucked a quick answer in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal already has a helper for this, in the shape of the [`element_validate_number()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/element_validate_number/7) validation callback:

```
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['number']['#element_validate'][] = 'element_validate_number';
}
```

You can also use [`element_validate_integer()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/element_validate_integer/7) or [`element_validate_integer_positive`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/element_validate_integer_positive/7) if either of those make more sense for your use case.

Comment: Unfortunately, the method is calling; however, it is not validating. I think the problem could be `number`. I named the field `number` so I assume that's the key of the array? The `fieldname` is `field_number`. How do I know what key to use? Similarly, how do I find out other elements keys?

Comment: I now get this error: `Notice: Undefined index: #value in element_validate_number() (line 4385 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\form.inc).`

Comment: Oh right, yeah that would've been helpful to know ;) So it'll be more like `$form['field_number'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#element_validate'][] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your validate function in `hook_form_<form_id>_alter($form, $form_state)`

like the following

```
<themeName>_form_user_register_form_alter($form, $form_state) {
// your rest of the code
$form['#validate'][] = "myfunc_form_user_register_form_validate";
}
```

Clear the cache afterwards and check if the function is properly called

Hope this will help!

Comment: This seems to work. However, `if (!is_numeric($form_state['values']['number'])) {` in my method doesn't validate correctly. Instead I have to make it: `is_numeric($form_state['values']['number']['und'][0]['value'])`